# Convert a Linksys WAG54GP2 ADSL router into Access point only to extend my Wifi range

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a wireless lan running on my ASDL2 connection. The router (Seimens Gigaset sx763) is provided by the ISP and is generally good. However I have couple of dead spots at the far end of the house and since I have my old router sitting in the drawer I thought that I'd try to convert it into simple WAP.

However downloading the manual from linksys it seems to be that the manual is from an earlier firmware, but the very first option on the very first page seems promising:

Wan Mode: Router or ADSL

However after this I'm a bit lost. I know that the wireless card on this box will need a mac address and it must get its address from the master router (I thought static might be best).

However the again the manual is out of date I have the option of

DHCP: ON or OFF or RELAY

I've not even got to the more complex options yet.

Question is can this device even work this way (seems like it but I cannot find any docs on it), and if so how?

Edit: Having now fiddled around I'm of the opinion that this cannot be done.

Comment: refer to the link to the manual in my answer, it has a link to a manual containing this information. Also, those above settings have nothing to do in making the router act as a repeater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** After looking through the [product manual](http://downloads.linksysbycisco.com/downloads/WAG54GP2_ug,1.pdf) of your [Linksys WAG54GP2 router](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/US/en/support/WAG54GP2/download), I'm convinced there is **no way** to set it up as a repeater / extender using the **default** firmware.

**Update2:** The options you mention, do not have anything to do with making the router an extender. But rather how it should function within the physical network you are plugging it in to.

---

Since you mention *A few deadspots*, maybe  you should consider getting a stronger antenna? Depending on the actual obstacles in the way, and distance to these deadsposts, this may actually remove the need for using the link WAG54GP2 as a repeater.

---

If you'd still like to make the WAG54GP2 work as a repeater for the wirless network, then what you'll most probably be needing is custom firmware to enable this functionallity (if it's supported) for your Linksys Wireless router like:

- [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com)
- [OpenWRT](http://www.openwrt.org/)

This howto gives instructions of how to [upgrade the WRTG54G2 to dd-wrt](http://blogs.gurulabs.com/mike/2009/03/upgrading-a-cisco-linksys-wrt5.html)

Also check out some of the threads on Superuser that cover the topic.

- [Can I make two wireless routers communicate using the wireless?](https://superuser.com/questions/19184/can-i-make-two-wireless-routers-communicate-using-the-wireless)
- [DD-WRT Router acting as a Switch and Wifi AP](https://superuser.com/questions/23545/dd-wrt-router-acting-as-a-switch-and-wifi-ap)
- [Which routers do you prefer for DD-WRT or OpenWRT?](https://superuser.com/questions/672/which-routers-do-you-prefer-for-dd-wrt-or-openwrt)
- [Selecting Home Networking Equipment](https://superuser.com/questions/13722/selecting-home-networking-equipment)

Comment: thank you. I do believe it works this way but don't have any concrete information about it.

Comment: I've updated my answer after reading though the product manual. And I'm convinced you **can't** use your router this way with the default frimware

Comment: This is the manual I downloaded. It doesn't show the option that appear in my firmaware. But thank you.

Comment: What version of the firmware are you using?

Comment: my Firmware Version: 2.01.06

Comment: Marking as accepted :-(

Answer (score 1):

IMO, most people do not realize that consumer WiFi routers can be used just as WAP i.e. not use the WAN port on the unit and follow this:

Cascade one of the LAN ports of your WiFi router with your central switch using a regular/cross over (which ever is applicable) CAT5 cable, and give the WiFi unit a static IP number.  Disable DHCP on the WiFi device if there is another DHCP server already on your LAN.  You can follow this procedure for any numbers of WiFi routers/APa - just ensure that you give them unique static IP addresses.

Give a different SSID and WPA2 pass phrase to your WiFi AP.  Done.

I have done such setups and it works!  No need to muck around with any special firmware.

Comment: thank you for this. I did consider this but I wanted to avoid the cabled connection between the two. With a cable I can connect the other pc's to the other device as a switch as well. However good to have this info here.